# How to display text after a value on a SSRS Report Builder template?

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to get some help on creating an expression to display text on an SSRS template.

The age value is stored in the database if captured. If the value was populated I would like to display the text `Years` after the age value. However, if the age is not populated I don't want the text to be displayed at all. I have tried the following expression, but it doesn't work:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!AgeAtMarriage.Value, "Index") = True, "Years" , " ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that AgeAtMarriage is numeric then you could do something like this

```
=IIF(VAL(First(Fields!AgeAtMarriage.Value)) = 0, "", "Years")
```

Comment: That's perfect Alan, thanks for all your help and quick reply